# Group by a pandas dataframe without loosing the columns multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

I have a df with multiindex columns that looks like this:

```
A          | B          | ...
bins | ... | bins | ... | ...
```

And I have this code to get the number of occurrences for each pair of 'bins':

`bin_sizes = df.groupby([(A, 'bins'), (B, 'bins')], as_index=False, group_keys=False).size()`

My problem is that the resulting dataframe's columns are not multiindex, and I need them to be the same as the original dataframe.

I tried the arguments `as_index=False` and `group_keys=False` in groupby but does not work as I expect

Here is an example:

```
# Dataframe with two level index columns
df = pd.DataFrame({('A', 'a'): [5,3,2], ('A', 'b'): [8,2,5], ('A', 'bins'): [1,1,2], ('B', 'a'): [5,3,2], ('B', 'b'): [8,2,5], ('B', 'bins'): [1,1,2]}, index=[0,1,2])
# df.columns.nlevels = 2
b = df.groupby([('A', 'bins'), ('B', 'bins')], group_keys=False, as_index=False).size()
# b.columns.nlevels = 1
```

Context:

The purpose is to get then, for each bin of 'A', the corresponding bin of 'B' with more occurrences. So I can filter my original dataframe by these pairs of bins. The idea is to use inner merge but 'it is not allowed between diferent levels'

```
idx = bin_sizes.groupby(('A', 'bins'))['size'].idxmax()
bins = bin_sizes.loc[idx]
merged = pd.merge(df, bins, on=[('A', 'bins'), ('B', 'bins')])
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is one of the options :

```
bins = df.xs("bins", level=1, axis=1)
size = bins.groupby(["A", "B"]).size()

out = df.loc[bins.agg(tuple, axis=1) == size.idxmax()]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   A          B        
   a  b bins  a  b bins
0  5  8    1  5  8    1
1  3  2    1  3  2    1
```

Comment: The xs method does the job, and it is smoother than the way I had to get the bins. But then 'size' is calculated as a series with bins in a multiindex, which I don't like for accessibility.
Anyway, on the last line 'size.idxmax()' returns a single bin tuple, so it's not what I'm looking for (I need for each of 'A' bins, the max occurrences of 'B' bin), and out result after the filter has 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I managed to make the filter I wanted, thanks in some way to [@Timeles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76525692/13152652) answer, like this:

```py
bins = df.xs('bins', level=1, axis=1).groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).size()

bins = bins.loc[bins.groupby('A')['size'].idxmax()]

df = df.loc[df[[('A', 'bins'), ('B', 'bins')]].agg(tuple, axis=1).isin(bins[['A', 'B']].agg(tuple, axis=1))]
```

But the question of the post itself has not been resolved.